# Is there a way to sort gmail using a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, sorting, gmail, bookmarklet

I was looking for a simple solution to sorting my Gmail by Sender, so that I can select all mail from a specific sender and archiving them, but I cannot find a working bookmarklet.  I have searched a few places and found the following bookmarklets:

```
javascript:function toArray (c) {var a, k;a = new Array;for (k=0; k < c.length; ++k)a[k] = c[k];return a;}function insAtTop(par,child) {if (par.childNodes.length)par.insertBefore(child, par.childNodes[0]);else par.appendChild(child);}function countCols(tab) {var nCols, i;nCols = 0;for(i = 0; i nCols)nCols = tab.rows[i].cells.length;return nCols;}function makeHeaderLink(colNo, ord, regex, numeric) {var link;link = document.createElement('a');link.href = '#';link.onclick = function() {var __st = window == top ? window : top;__st.sortTable(colNo, ord, regex, numeric);return false;};link.appendChild(document.createTextNode((ord>0)? 'asc':'desc'));return link;}function makeSortControl(header, col, title, regex, numeric) {header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title + ' ['));header.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(col, 1, regex, numeric));header.appendChild(document.createTextNode('/'));header.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(col, -1, regex, numeric));header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(']'));}function makeHeader(nCols) {var header, headerCell, i;header = document.createElement('span');/*put links in columns 2 and 4 only (sender, subject)*/makeSortControl(header, 2, 'Sender(s)');header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' | '));makeSortControl(header, 4, 'Subject');header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' | '));makeSortControl(header, 2, 'Thread Activity', /\(\d*\)$/, true);return header;}function getWidestTable(tables) {var maxTable = undefined;var maxWidth = -1;for (var i = 0; i= maxWidth && table.id != '') {maxWidth = table.clientWidth;maxTable = table;}}return maxTable;}function getAllTables() {g_tables = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table'));var iframe = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');if (!iframe)return null;var iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument.document || iframe.contentWindow.document;iframetables = toArray(iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('table'));if (iframetables.length)g_tables = g_tables.concat(iframetables);if (!g_tables.length)return null;return g_tables;}(function () {/* ---- main() ---- ENTRY POINT HERE ------------------------- */g_tables = getAllTables();if (!g_tables) {alert("It seems that this script is not compatible with your gmail version (no tables), giving up!");return;}inboxtable = getWidestTable(g_tables);if (inboxtable.id.length<4) {alert("It seems that this script is not compatible with your gmail version (no inbox), giving up!");return;}var control = makeHeader(countCols(inboxtable));var tableparent = inboxtable.parentNode.parentNode;while(tableparent.previousSibling.style.display == 'none')tableparent = tableparent.previousSibling;tableparent.previousSibling.appendChild(control);/*tableparent.parentNode.insertBefore(control, tableparent);*/}) ();function compareRows(a,b) {if (a.sortKey == b.sortKey)return 0;return (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) ? g_order : -g_order;}function compareRowsNumeric(a,b) {if (a.sortKey == b.sortKey)return 0;return ((a.sortKey + '').match(/\d+/) - (b.sortKey + '').match(/\d+/)) * g_order;}function sortTable(colNo, ord, regex, numeric) {var table, rows, nR, bs, i, j, temp;g_order = ord;g_colNo = colNo;g_tables = getAllTables();table = getWidestTable(g_tables);rows = new Array();nR = 0;bs = table.tBodies;for (i = 0; i < bs.length; ++i)for(j=0; j < bs[i].rows.length; ++j) {rows[nR] = bs[i].rows[j];temp = rows[nR].cells[g_colNo];if (!temp)rows[nR].sortKey = '';else if (!regex)rows[nR].sortKey = temp.textContent.toLowerCase();else {var val = temp.textContent.toLowerCase().match(regex);rows[nR].sortKey = val ? val : '';}++nR;}if (numeric)rows.sort(compareRowsNumeric);else rows.sort(compareRows);for (i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)insAtTop(table.tBodies[0], rows[i]);}
```

That one doesn't work, and neither does this one:

```
javascript:(function(){function%20f(r){var%20t=r.getElementsByTagName(“td”);var%20d,s;var%20i,j;for(i=0;ib)return%201;return%200} function%20sl(m){var%20l=Array.prototype.slice.call(m.getElementsByTagName(“tr”),0); if(!l.length)return;var%20b=l[0].parentNode;var%20s=[];for(var%20i=0;i
```

Could you tell me if there is a way to achieve this by using a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a GMail filter work for this?  Next to the "Search the Web" button at the top of the GMail page is "Create a filter".

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't sort multiple senders, only one.  At least that is all I know how to sort.

Comment: separate the email addresses with `OR` e.g. `me@mine.com OR you@yours.com`